# Changing default symbols bound to option key?

Tags: keybindings

When I type ⌥ and some letter a special character usually shows up - this would be really useful except for the fact that I have no use for a lot of these characters.  How can I customize which characters are bound to these shortcuts?

Comment: what Mac and OSX are you using.

Comment: Macbook Air 2011, OSX 10.9.4

Answer (score 3):

Create the folder `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and in it create a file called `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and add whatever special character you need like so:

```
{
    "~c" = (insertText:, "⌘");
}
```

This makes <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> insert the symbol `⌘`. For more information on this file and its syntax refere to [this article](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html). After editing the file you need to restart your application for the changes to take effect.